# How to make `NSPopUpButton` with `NSControl.ControlSize.mini` programmatically?

Tags: appkit, nspopupbutton

- I tried setting `controlSize`, and it didn't work.
- I tried setting `NSMenuItem.attributedTitle`, and it didn't work.
  Setting `NSMenuItem.attributedTitle` made text smaller, but didn't make checkmarks smaller. Therefore result looks broken.

[image: code-made-popup]

Here's code to reproduce.

```
let testFont1 = NSFont.menuFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize(for: .mini))
let menu1 = NSMenu()

menu1.font = testFont1
menu1.addItem(withTitle: "AAA", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
let item2 = NSMenuItem()
item2.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "BBB", attributes: [.font: testFont1])
menu1.addItem(item2)

let popup1 = NSPopUpButton()
popup1.menu = menu1
popup1.controlSize = .mini
popup1.sizeToFit()

window.contentView?.addSubview(popup1)
```

How to make a mini-sized pop-up button properly with no NIB and only code?

Answer (score 2):

Just assign mini-size font to the `NSPopUpButton` instance.

```
popup1.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize(for: .mini))
```

Nothing else is really required. The code can be shorten like this.

```
let popup1 = NSPopUpButton()
popup1.controlSize = .mini
popup1.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize(for: .mini))
popup1.addItem(withTitle: "AAA")
popup1.addItem(withTitle: "BBB")
popup1.sizeToFit()
window.contentView?.addSubview(popup1)
```

This applies equally to any other control-based classes. You need to set both `controlSize` and `font`. It seems `controlSize` controls only graphical appearance part and `font` controls text renderings.